# Creating a log-in system over wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, authentication, wordpress-theming

i'm need to create a registration/log-in system in a wordpress site. 
the authentication will be with an external API source.
i have created basic log-in systems in the past, but never over WP. 
the general flow of application is :

log-in submit -> API authentication -> log-in user. 
log-out submit -> API authentication -> log-out user.

the part that i am interested in  is the third one ( after authentication ). 
what should be the process of checking if user is logged-in ( `$_SESSION` ? DB ? BOTH ? )

the process i'm thinking about is following: 
1) user logs in - create new session - and save sessionID in cookie. 
2) in theme `index.php` check if isset `$_session(sessionID)`
3) if yes - `$var=in; else $var=out`; 
2) each page check if $var==in or out.

is this a good way of planning a secure log-in in wordpress ?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress login system is alredy secured but if you want to add your external authentication, insead of building all the login system by yourself, you can simply call your external API using the wp_login action hook.

The wp_login action hook is triggered when a user logs in using the standard wp-login page, and you can execute your code there.

```
<?php
function your_function($user_login, $user) {
    // enter your external authentification API call here
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
?>
```

Use the $user variable to retrieve the user data you want from the wp database

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

Comment: thanks for the answer - but i need it to be a custom form displayed in website headers - and not through the WP login page

Comment: That's not a problem, you can use the **wp_login_form** function that provides a simple login form for use anywhere in the website.
Or you can create your own custom form, then use the function **wp_signon()** to authentificate the user.
These will also trigger the wp_login action hook so you can use it to add an external authentification if you want.

Comment: but will that mean that the wp_signon() need to authenticate the user info with his info in DB ( like the WP login form ) ?

Comment: Yes it does, wp_signon() authentificate the user according to the data stored in wp_users table in the WP database

Comment: thanks but i have no need in saving user data in my DB.

Comment: all of my data will be stored in external sources.